# google sheet IMPORTXML Xpath returns #N/A

Tags: xml, google-sheets, xpath, google-sheets-formula

I'm not sure what I did wrong to get the #N/A back

This is the command I use
`=IMPORTXML("https://pantip.com/topic/41020158", "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[7]/div/span")`

[This is the site I want to scrape.](https://pantip.com/topic/35241832)

This is the part I want to scrape
[image]

I don't know what's the difference that I can't scrape with this method.
because i tried this command
`=IMPORTXML("https://pantip.com/topic/41020158", "/html/body/div[4]/div/div/div[3]/div/div[2]/h2")`

It can scrape the title.

I want to scrape the web content with IMPORTXML, but it returns #N/A so I don't understand what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I don't know what you want to scrape.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
=importxml(url,"//h2|//span[@class='caption']")
```

[image]

or

```
=transpose(importxml(A1,"//div[@class='display-post-story']"))
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your reply.
But that's not the part I want to scrape, I want to scrape the total number of comments.
I've attached a picture of the part I want to scrape.

Comment: This is not possible, The number is a parameter inside the code source `<span class="title"><i class="icon-header-badge3 chat"></i>{{:count}} ความคิดเห็น</span>` and loaded by ajax.